# javascript function calling methods

Tags: javascript, function

I found the following way of calling prototype methods in javascript :

```
this.abc(x,y,z).cnt;
```

What will this statement call, the arguments and what will be the return values.
I saw this kind of usage in my application that Im currently working on.

Answer (score 2):

`this.abc(x,y,z).cnt` means

- `.abc` is a method of your current object (or whatever `this` is defined to be)
- `.abc` accepts `x`, `y`, `z` and returns an object
- The returned object has a property called `cnt`
- `this.abc(x,y,z).cnt` basically gets the value of that property

If you are familiar with languages like Python, it is equivalent to

```
self.abc(x, y, z)["cnt"]
```

Comment: ya fine thanks. As I have not used that pattern, I got confused whether will there any arg manipulation while passing values to the prototype method

Answer (score 0):

That `this` call method `abc` with parameter `x,y,z` and then take `cnt` property.

Look at this example, and focus to variable **data** in `abc` method.

```
// init a class
function Obj(){}

// add method abc
Obj.prototype.abc = function(x, y, z) {
    var cnt = x + y + z;
    var data = {cnt: cnt};

    // return object with cnt property
    return data;
}

const obj = new Obj();
const x = 1, y = 2, z = 3;

// cnt = 6
var cnt = obj.abc(x,y,z).cnt;

// equal with this
var data = obj.abc(x, y, z);
console.log(data.cnt)
```